# Wrong week from date component on IOS5

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

My region format is US, and I'm getting different week numbers from the ones I get on Mac OSx which is also in US.
I'm using iOS 5 and have not programmed on iOS before this sdk version. So I just want to make sure I'm not doing something wrong. Whit this code below I'm getting for the last week of the year the number 53 which I think is wrong. My first day of the week is set to sunday.
Please advice, thank you.

```
 NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];


    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSWeekCalendarUnit) fromDate:date ];
    int week = (int)[dateComponents week];


    NSLog(@"%i", week);
```

Being [NSDate date] december 8, it returns week number 50, but on Mac OSX I get week 49

Comment: what is `self`?  a `NSDate` object?  I think you're going to need to show more code than this.  What I'd be looking for would be how you set up the `NSDate` you pass to your `dateComponents` object.

Comment: thank you, its a category on NSDate, so self is date, I edited to expose the code more easily

Answer (score 1):

First off, I see you changed your code to get rid of the 'gregorianCalendar' nonsense.  Good.

When I tried your code in a test app:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar]; 
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSWeekCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
int week = (int)[dateComponents week];
[calendar release];
NSLog( @"week is %d", week);
return week;
```

I'm getting 49 (which makes sense to me).

If you're getting 53, then you're passing in the wrong date.

Comment: I'm getting 50 with that code, what sdk version are you using?

Comment: I'm getting 50 with that code under XCode 4.2.X and iOS 5... I was getting 49 with that same code under XCode 3.2.6 and iOS 4.3 SDK.  Interesting difference in behavior, yes?

Comment: More like a bug I think, I filed it just in case: bug# 10549802. I cannot think of a scenario where the last week is 53. In europe they use ourWeek-1, not +1

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the locale? There are cases where the week numbers differ between the US and Europe for example.